# cost of either running test and adding char or removing at the end?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

What's the fastest/least resource costing move when concatenating string together from things like datatables?  For example:

```
     for (int i = 0; i < darray.Length; i++)
            {
                str_orderbycity += darray[i]["Sort_Order"].ToString() + ",";
                if (i < (darray.Length - 1))
                {
                    str_orderbycity += ",";
                }
            }
```

or waiting till the end and then running the remove method on the string:

```
      str_orderbycity = str_orderbycity.Remove(str_orderbycity.Length - 1, 1);
```

I'm just curious...

Thanks

Comment: The biggest issue with concatenating strings like this is that the .Net framework will intern each copy of the string as you step through, which means a big build-up in memory.  The `StringBuilder` below is the best way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `StringBuilder` object, surely?

e.g.

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < darray.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(darray[i]["Sort_Order"].ToString());
            sb.Append(",");
        }

        if (darray.Length > 0)
            sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
```

It's sole function is to build strings.  See [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

And, I believe, it's better to test once after the loop, and then remove.

Comment: It depends upon data array length. If no. of strings are less, `String` is the way to go. Otherwise `StringBuilder`.

Comment: 'If no of strings are less'?  Less than what?

Comment: That has to be measured/profiled. No specific number.[Performance considerations for strings in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10318/Performance-considerations-for-strings-in-C)

Comment: Thanks, I don't know what it is but i've been slow to adopt string builders but from this point forward I will...  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

When you use concatenation such as

```
str_orderbycity += ",";
```

A new string is created (if not already existing in [string intern pool](http://brainspeex.wordpress.com/2011/10/30/string-pooling-in-net-c/)).

[StringBuffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) avoids those intermediate strings by using maintaining `char array` only.

`StringBuffer` has its costs/overheads so it is not always efficient than `String` concatenation.

From [String Builder Performance consideration - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx)

> The performance of a concatenation operation for a String or StringBuilder object depends on the frequency of memory allocations.
>   A String concatenation operation always allocates memory, whereas a StringBuilder concatenation operation allocates memory only if the StringBuilder object buffer is too small to accommodate the new data.
>   Use the String class if you are concatenating a fixed number of String objects. In that case, the compiler may even combine individual concatenation operations into a single operation.
>   Use a StringBuilder object if you are concatenating an arbitrary number of strings; for example, if you're using a loop to concatenate a random number of strings of user input.

Answer (score 0):

Use string.Join:

string myStr = string.Join(",", myArray.Select(n => n.ToString()).ToArray())

Do a search on converting an array to csv for more info.